# validation of video uploading not working

Tags: javascript, php, validation

I am allowing my website visitors to upload the video files . But i want to restrict the size and type of the videos . I am using the below code for validating, but its not working at all.

```
      function validation(thisform)
         {
            with(thisform)
         {
               if(validateFileExtension(file, "valid_msg", "Only Videos are allowed!",
              new Array("mp4","flv")) == false)
              {
                    return false;
          }
                 if(validateFileSize(file,6291456, "valid_msg",        "Document size should be less than 6MB !")==false)
             {
             return false;
               }
            }
               }
          </script>  




          <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form" onsubmit="return validation(this)">
           <label for="" class="col-sm-5 control-label">Upload Your Video</label>
           <div class="col-sm-5">
          <input type="file" name="video"  id="i_file"> 
           <div id="valid_msg"/>
           <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save my Profile" name="register" style="background-color:#31B9A0; border:1px solid #fff; font-weight:bold;" id="B1"/>
```

Comment: Please post the contents of the validateFileExtension and validateFileSize functions - these are not Javascript built-ins. Additionally, please read this regarding the `with` statement: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with

Comment: @AndrewKlatzke   any other alternative code through which i can achieve validating this ?

Answer (score 1):

Using just JS, do the following:

```
document.getElementById("i_file").addEventListener("change", function () {
    var file = this.files[0];

    if (file) {
        var mbSize = file.size / 1024 / 1024;
        var fileIsMp4 = (file.type === "video/mp4");

        if (mbSize > 1 || !fileIsMp4) {
            alert("failure");
        } else {
            alert("success");
        }
    }
});
```

Using jQuery, you can do the following:

```
$("#i_file").on("change", function(){
  var file = this.files[0];

  if( file )
  {
      var mbSize = file.size/1024/1024;   
      var fileIsMp4 = (file.type === "video/mp4");

      if( mbSize > 1 || ! fileIsMp4 )
      {
          // do your rejection code
      }
      else
      {
          // do your success code
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: Downvoted for providing a jQuery answer to a specifically JavaScript question.

Comment: @IanDevlin This was tagged as jQuery, above.

Comment: Then the OP used the wrong tags, his/her code is clearly not jQuery, but I will remove both the tag and my downvote for this reason! Sorry!

Comment: @IanDevlin No problem, edited to add the JS-only answer now that the tag is removed. Thanks!

Comment: @Andrew Klatzke - i put alertbox messsage in //do your rejection code and in // do your success code . will my alert box pop up when i choose a file or when does it work when the submit is clicked ?

Comment: @SAYUJRAGHAVAN give it another shot - forgot a closing brace when I copied it over from JSFiddle. It will trigger on upload, not form submit.